# Запись данных из формы в текстовый файл

Tags: php

Данные, находящиеся в `<textarea name="textblock"></textarea>`, сохраняются в текстовый файл textfile.txt вот этим скриптом:

```
<?php
// Открыть текстовый файл
$f = fopen("title/textfile.txt", "w");
// Записать текст
fwrite($f, $_POST["textblock"]); 
// Закрыть текстовый файл
fclose($f);
// Открыть файл для чтения и прочитать строку
$f = fopen("title/textfile.txt", "r");
// Читать текст
echo fgets($f); 
fclose($f);
?>
```

Но при этом каждая новая запись затирает предыдущую. Как прописать так, чтобы каждая новая запись происходила в новый файл (1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt, ...)?

Comment: А зачем вы после записи в файл читаете заново его содержимое? Думаете, оно будет отличаться от того, что содержится в `$_POST["textblock"]`?

Comment: Это видимо проверка. Вдруг в файл ничего не записалось. Исключения? Не не слышал...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое решение:

```
<?php
//определяем имя файла
$file_name = "title/" . strval(count(glob('./title')) + 1) . ".txt";
// Открыть текстовый файл
$f = fopen($file_name, "w");
...
```

`glob('./title')` - тут вместо `'./title'` пропишите путь к каталогу, где хранятся ваши файлы.

Но я бы на вашем месте имя файла выбирал бы таким, чтобы оно дату содержало:

```
<?php
//создаем объект DateTime с текущей датой
$date = date_create();
//определяем имя файла
$file_name = "title/" . date_format($date, 'YmdHis.u') . ".txt";
// Открыть текстовый файл
$f = fopen($file_name, "w");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Поменяй `w` на `a` или `a+`

Новые записи будут записываться в один файл и не будут затирать предыдущие.

- **'r'** - открыть только для чтения, помещает указатель на начало файла;
- **'r+'** - открыть для чтения и для записи, помещает указатель на начало файла;
- **'w'** - открыть только для записи, помещает указатель на начало файла и очищает все содержимое файла, если файл не существует, создается новый файл;
- **'w+'** - открыть для чтения и для записи, помещает указатель на начало файла и очищает все содержимое файла, если файл не существует, создается новый файл;
- **'a'** - открыть только для записи, помещает указатель на конец файла, если файл не существует, создается новый файл;
- **'a+'** - открыть для чтения и для записи, помещает указатель на конец файла, если файл не существует, создается новый файл.